# the best algorithm to compare set of coordinates in database

Tags: sql, algorithm, gis, spatial

i'm trying to query for the nearest locations for a specified location 
i've considered getting the distance between each point and the one i have but i think it would take a lot of time, may be O(n^2), is there any better way

Comment: Many databases have Spatial/GIS (geographic information systems) extensions built to make these searches easier.  These use a type of index called R-D trees that greatly improve the performance of this type of query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look into using a [K-D tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a [quad-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_tree) or [oct-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oct-tree). They're actually not too difficult to implement and there are good examples on the web.

This is called [Nearest-Neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), and Wikipedia has a host of information on it.

You can in general do much better than O(n<sup>2</sup>) using these methods.

The basic outline of a K-D tree is this:

1. Sort your coordinates on X and choose the value in the middle. This
   becomes the root node of a tree. Other values are split left and
   right.
2. On the left and right subtrees, sort the coordinates in y, and
   choose the value in the middle, this becomes the root of the
   subtree.
3. Repeat on further subtrees making sure to split on X, then Y, then
   X, then Y.
4. When querying your tree, you can simply go down it like you would a binary search tree
   based on how the data was split. The nearest neighbor will be the last node you land on
   or its parent (I think, it's been a little while).

Edit: If you're looking for the K-nearest neighbors, when you search your K-D tree, you search in a range specified by a rectangle. You can search the subtree in a same way, but instead you must make sure the entire rectangle would be left, right, above, or below a node (based on how you split). If a node is contained in the rectangle, recurse on its subtrees. You can still in principle do better than O(n<sup>2</sup>) using this approach.

Comment: Co-ordinate is a sphere? How do you solve this problem?

Comment: @Phpdna: 1) Not everyone operates on a sphere. 2) All the methods I talked about are still applicable. Based on what OP has already tried, the methods I suggested are actually probably more applicable and easier to implement.

Comment: Can you elaborate? lat lng is angle. How do yousave in k-d tree?

Comment: @Phpdna: You can split latitude and longitude just like you do (x, y).  If you really want, you can transform the coordinates into points on a sphere with (x, y, z) coordinates (assuming a uniform sphere) that you can then apply a k-d tree to. See the Wikipedia article about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: :Imo question is about distance and not trees. But how do you query an octree?

Comment: @Phpdna: I believe OP already has a distance metric for their coordinates (most likely Euclidean norm). I'm not sure if you're being serious about how to search an octtree? There's plenty of information on this accessible via a simple web search.

Comment: @AndyQ:What's the problem? How do query (x,y,z) without the distance? He gives you points that's all. Did you ask him?

Answer (score 0):

A quadkey reduce the dimensions and it's similar to a fractal. A quadkey is also used for tiling for example in Bing maps. You can try my php solution hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It gives the hilbert curve but also the quadkey. But it's not an exact search. If you want to refine the search you need the harvesine formula. You can use a bounding box to speed up the search.